# Lose hope about life / Lose hope on life / Lose hope over life

Tags: prepositions

> Lose hope about life

/

> Lose hope on life

/

> Lose hope over life

What are the differences in these 3 sentences? 
And how are they used? 
Do all of them make the same meaning like "No hope from life." ?

Comment: I would say (and this might be true any time you are referring to life in general) you can just leave off the preposition and the word “life” and write “lose hope.” That said, only the first one sounds remotely natural to me. I would say “lose hope _for_ life” or “lose hope _in_ life”. I think whether one has hope or loses it, it comes _from_ the subject and can only really be _for_ a positive outcome _in_ a given arena.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard or read losing hope on or over life.  Usually, we hear "lose/give up hope of life" or "lose hope for life".  Sometimes, we also hear "lose hope in or about life". The use of over or on here sounds rather unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is about the prepositions *'about', 'on' and 'over'*. Okay, let's take one by one.

> Lose hope **about** life -- *about* as a preposition is generally used to [mean](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=about) *with regard or relation to; on the subject of.*

The preposition *about* makes the topic *broader.* If I ask this question, the answer is in detail.

> What do you think **about** life? ~ Ah, life is all *about* enjoying every moment. It's *about* falling and then rising and never giving up...it's *about* loving someone truly and be loved, it's *about* caring your family and do something for society... blah...blah...blah...

Now the second one,

> Lose hope **on** life --*on* as a preposition here is referring *life* **directly.** Straightforwardly.

If I ask someone using that preposition, the answer is quite straightforward.

> Can anyone rely **on** their lives? ~ No, life is uncertain!

The third one (which is weird!)

> Lose hope **over** life -- on the very first glance, I thought you are *comparing* ***hope over life!*** In other words, this sentence gives the listener the message of losing hope *in the contrast of* life!

Something like... *I'll choose money **over** fame.*

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hope%20on%20life,%20hope%20about%20life,%20hope%20over%20life&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,hope%20on%20life;,c0;.t1;,hope%20about%20life;,c0) shows this result:

[image]

And yes, all mean 'Life's hopeless!'